# Can't figure out postgres syntax in custom migration builder C#. Concating two columns into one

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-migrations

Basically what I'm doing is trying to do custom migration where I create a column FullName and take the values of columns FirstName, LastName and put them into column FullName.

That's what I'm trying. It's been an hour or so and I can't figure out the syntax, been all over the internet and tried all the syntax I found.

```
migrationBuilder.Sql(@"
    UPDATE USER
    SET FullName = FirstName + ' ' + LastName
");
```

That's the error.

```
  SqlState: 42601
    MessageText: syntax error at or near "User"
    Position: 25
    File: scan.l
    Line: 1188
    Routine: scanner_yyerror
42601: syntax error at or near "User"

POSITION: 25
```

I tried all the variations of syntax found in the internet.

Comment: update statment looks fine for me ... but isn't `USER` a keyword in postgress ? (in MSSQL i would use `[USER]` instead not mentions that table should be named as plurals) are you sure that you `USER` table is in default scheme? (in other case you shou use `SCHEMA.USER`) and finally did you tried to add semicolon at the end?

Comment: Apart from `user` being a reserved keyword: the string concatenation operator in SQL is `||` - the `+` is there to add numbers

Comment: Tried adding semicolon at the end and using ||, still the same error. SCHEMA.USER =  42P01: relation "schema.user" does not exist.

Comment: "*relation "schema.user" does not exist*" - apparently there is no table named `"user"` in the schema named `schema`

Comment: I changed the name to Users, dropped the database and did new migration. PgAdmin shows that there's clearly table "Users" and when I lunch query console in the Rider it even suggests me "Users" table when I start to type Us.., migration also shows that there's table "Users" so I don't know how there can't be relation.

Comment: `"Users"` is a different table name than `"User"` or `"user"`

Comment: Yes I see, but I just changed the name of previous table "User" to "Users". In my database there's only one "Users" table and when I want to use migrationbuilder.Sql() for custom migration it doesn't find relation to the "Users" table for some reason but the table exist in the database.